# docker node ls doesn't change the promoted node's manager status to reachable

Tags: docker, swarm

I have 1 manager node (swarm-manager) and two worker nodes (swarm-worker01 and swarm-worker02). I typed the command `docker node promote swarm-worker01` it gave me this output:

```
 Node swarm-worker01 promoted to a manager in the swarm.
```

But `docker node ls` doesn't say anything about swarm-worker01 being a manager:

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
oaquxnmku3s4uhrcp29ijx7rn *   swarm-manager       Ready               Active              Leader              19.03.4
xfwywb5wu550lme0epcexrgu1     swarm-worker01      Ready               Active                                  19.03.4
afyhz03k7uoejnm5dlht98ip5     swarm-worker02      Ready               Active                                  19.03.4
```

I if try to promote the node again I get the message:

```
Node xfwywb5wu550lme0epcexrgu1 is already a manager.
```

My API version is 1.40

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: @LinPy I'm already in the manager environment

Comment: what is your API version ?

Comment: @LinPy I have updated the question, my API version is 1.40

Comment: try this `docker swarm join --token <manager_token> <ip>`, you may first remove it from the cluster with leave

Comment: I think your cluster is fine. Just try to run something.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and resolved the issue by making sure that the worker node being promoted has the port 2377 open, which is required for a manager to function.

Comment: Expanding Chakri 's answer, since docker communicates using HTTP if you promote a worker node to a manager before adding the 2377/tcp port to the firewall-cmd the node's state will not be up-to-date as a manager it will still show to (docker node ls) with its previous status. 
However, to the docker swarm, that particular node is already a manager. 
Dues, the conflicting messages you have, @Yashar

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @chakri Here are all ports listet:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts

So basicly get sure that each node can handle this:

- TCP port 2377 for cluster management communications
- TCP and UDP port 7946 for communication among nodes
- UDP port 4789 for overlay network traffic